# C++ set -- number of elements with a key less than x

Tags: c++, set, stdset

I have a `set<int>` and I want to see how many elements in it are less than x. (x is also int)

What should i do?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `lower_bound` to compute `std::distance(s.begin(), s.lower_bound(x))`. (If `x` is a key, this counts the number of elements strictly *before* `x`.)

Comment: Relevant link pertaining to the complexity of this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321013/c-set-counting-elements-less-than-a-value

Comment: Yup, it's O(n) which isn't nice at all

Comment: @LeoLeontev: well, it's O(n) in iterator increments, not in applications of the predicate. If this sort of counting is your hot path, then you may prefer a "flat set" implementation where your iterators are random-access and you can compute differences in constant time.