# C++ set: counting elements less than a value

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, stl, complexity-theory

Assuming a I have an STL `set <int> s` and an `int x`, how can I count the number of elements in `s` that are less than `x`?

I'm seeking an `O(log n)` (or similar; anything that's reasonably better than `O(n)`) solution;

I already know about `std::distance(s.begin(), s.lower_bound(x))`, but that's `O(n)`, I believe, because `set`s aren't random-access.

Comment: You cannot do it with standard C++ set.

Comment: Why not use a binary search tree that supports these sorts of order statistics?  If it is red-black BST, it will guarantee log(n) performance even in the worst case.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Not even with a helper data-structure that might be updated simultaneously?

Comment: @angelatlarge I'll look into that; I implemented red-black trees before, so I guess this might work.

Comment: Most likely such a helper data-structure would be not simpler to implement than augmented RB-tree.

Comment: Would a [flat set](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx) suit your needs?

Comment: @MM. `std::set`s are always sorted.

Comment: @Oswald: My mistake, I thought it was a `vector` !!

Comment: you can  have a some performance , since set is sorted. You can use the 
     
    std::set<int>::iterator iter= s.find(x);
       if(iter != s.end(){
          return 0;  // O(1)
       }else{

         std::distance( s.begin(),iter); // O(n); depend on x could be less than n
       }

Comment: By the way, you don't need to implement augmented tree yourself. There are "GNU Policy-Based STL" structures. Also something like this is proposed for inclusion into Boost.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Insertion seems to be an issue.

Comment: @Abody97: Yep, that's the cost, but there are a lot of benefits.  You need to test it out to see if it's worth it for your particular application.  In my own experience, the benefits of contiguous storage have, more often than not, outweighed the costs of linear insertion and deletion.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need is an 'order-statistics tree'. It is essentially an augmented (binary search) tree that supports the additional operation `rank(x)` which gives you the number of elements with less or equal key as element `x`. Chapter 14 in Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein; "Introduction to Algorithms" should give you the algorithmic background.

There is also some implementation on the [web](http://sourceforge.net/projects/orderstatistics/).

Answer (score 7):

As a follow up to my comment: using red-black binary search trees (instead of sets), if each node stores the number of nodes rooted in that node (updated every time you insert/delete a node) then you can get at "number of nodes more than/less than X" statistics quite fast.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that's possible. Your STL set is a tree-based structure, so even just checking an element's presence is O(log n). Your tree's nodes do not store their subbranches' sizes in any field (as far as I know), so the number of operations needed for counting nodes that have some property which does not follow directly from the rules used for building the tree cannot be smaller than the number of these nodes. Since you don't know in advance how many nodes have values smaller than x, the worst-case performance is when all nodes are smaller than x, which means O(n) worst-case complexity.  Even if value x was in the tree, you need O(log n) operations to find that node but then need to visit all its left descendands in order to count them, so the complexity depends on the number of matching nodes which is O(n) in worst case. Perhaps with additional data in the tree's nodes, one could do better than that.