# Query on all contiguous subarray of size K

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures

Let's define an operation on an array `B[1:K]` of size `K` i.e. count the number of elements in the subarray `B[2:K]` which are smaller than `B[1]`.

Now I have an array `A[1:N]` of size `N` and my objective is to perform the above operation on all contiguous subarray of size `K`.

Example

`A = [4, 3, 6, 2, 1] and K = 3` There are `3` contiguous subarray of size of `3`.

1. `B = [4, 3, 6]` `count = 1` `[(3 < 4)]`
2. `B = [3, 6, 2]` `count = 1` `[(2 < 3)]`
3. `B = [6, 2, 1]` `count = 2` `[(2 < 6), (1 < 6)]`

Time complexity of the brute force approach will be `O((N-K+1)*K)` since performing the above operation on a contiguous subarray of size `K` is `O(K)`.

I can do it efficiently i.e in `Nlog(M)` if I can design a data structure 
which has the following properties

1. Insertion in `log(M)`
2. Deletion in `log(M)`
3. Count number of elements smaller than `X` in `log(M)`

I am `C++` user and I don't think there's any data structure that fulfills all mentioned requirements. Are there other ways to improve? Please help.

Comment: The first two is `std::set`, but the last operation will be `O(M)` despite the fact that finding the upper bound is `O(logM)` itself.

Comment: If your objective is just to count I have a algorithm in mind which runs in O(nlogn)

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes, I know that.

Comment: @marvel308 Yes, the count will be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use set with additional operation of counting elements less than k. This can be implemented as binary search tree (classic set implementation) with additional statistic in each node (basically size of the node in the tree).

More details here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15321444/1391392
And some implementation here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/orderstatistics/

Other option, which might look more straighforward is to use skiplists.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list

Answer (score 0):

Does this help ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <set>
using namespace std;
int bit[100005]={0};
// using BIT since numbers can repeat and set won't work
void update(int idx, int val, int n){
    while(idx < n){
        bit[idx] += val;
        idx += (idx & -idx);
    }
}
int get(int idx){
    int ret = 0;
    while(idx > 0){
        ret += bit[idx];
        idx -= (idx & -idx);
    }
    return ret;
}
int main() {
    int n, a[100005] = {0}, i, ans=0, k, maxx = -1;
    scanf("%d%d", &n, &k);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        if(maxx < a[i]){
            maxx = a[i];
        }
    }
    maxx++;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i] = maxx - a[i];
    }

    // now the problem becomes the opposite of what it initially was
    // now a[i] would contribute to ans if we can find an element a[j] where a[j] < a[i] and (i-j)<=k

    for(i=0;i<n;i++){
        if(i-k>=0){
            // remove i-k'th element from the BIT since it doesn't contribute
            update(a[i-k], -1, maxx);   
        }
        if(i >= k-1){
            // add how a[i] is gonna contribute to the final answer, it would be the number of elements less than a[i]
            ans += get(a[i]);
        }
        // add a[i] to the BIT
        update(a[i], 1, maxx);
    }
    printf("%d\n", ans);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This code make an assumption that all elements of the array are in the `[0, 100004]` range. It may not hold. It can be modified to work for arbitrary values of the elements `a` by mapping all numbers into the `[0, N - 1]` range before running your algorithm.