# Algorithm to find weighted ranking?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, ranking, weighted

**I want to find the rank of a person based on different parameters and each parameter has different weights assigned to them.**

For e.g. Suppose if there are three items a, b and c, these items could have any value between 0 to 10,00,000. There are weights assigned to them a = 0.3 , b=0.2, c=0.1. Suppose there are 10,000 people have these items with different quantity. Suppose a person X have items a=2200, b = 4000, c= 1280. Then how could I find the rank of person x within 10,000 people that where he lies.

Please let me know if needs more details.

Immediate help appreciated.

Comment: do you eventually need all the ranks anyway? or just need few people's rank?

Comment: @TomerW I need algorithm so that I can find rank of any person.

Comment: if you eventually need all ranks, just loop them and calculate  People.Foreach(p: R = A*wA+B*wB+C*wC)

Comment: @TomerW it is right but number of people could extend to any number so looping them slows the performance, so I want how can I find rank of randomly selected person.

Comment: @HuyNguyen it is the best example i can simplify the problem. If you need any understanding please do let me know.

Comment: i don't understand what is the input? find rank by person index or find person with rank number?

Comment: @ksanjay: in order to find the rank by any criterion of an object in an unsorted collection, you need to sort the collection by that criterion. The fact that you are using a weighted sum of several measures does not alter that reality. If you wanted to find Bob's rank by height in an unsorted collection of people, you would have to examine the height of everyone in the collection.

Comment: First, calculate the weight value of all people and store it in an array. Then sort the array. Now you have a sorted rank list of people based on their weight. Now for every random query calculate the person's weight and then find the upper bound position of the weight from the sorted array using binary search, the upper bound position is the rank of that person. Here the pre-processing takes `O(n)` times and every query takes `O(logN)` times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, calculate the weighted points of all persons.
That is,

```
P[i] = Wa * a[i] + Wb * b[i] + Wc * c[i];
```

Then sort all `P[i]` by its values.

You can define and use the custom compare function to get rank easily.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) rank[i] = i;
    sort (rank, rank + n, [P](int i, int j) {
        return P[i] < P[j];
    });
```

In case of dynamic insert and get rank operation, you have to use [order-statistics tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree).
Then you can get the performance result of `O(logn)` for both operations.

Please refer [codeforces](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/11080) and this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15321013/c-set-counting-elements-less-than-a-value) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but looping through all the persons will slows down the performance I want to rank any random people.

Comment: @ksanjay, so you mean dynamic addiction of people and get rank of random person?

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: I made edits for my answer, Is that what you want?

Comment: let me check...